# Copy last 4 array keys and values and add them onto end of the same array but with a different key name

Tags: php, arrays

I've looked at other questions and answers, but nothing quite helps me with this.

I've got an array of items for example like this (the amount of items varies):

```
'harry' => 'dog',
'bob' => 'badger',
'george' => 'toad',
'fred' => 'frog',
'lucy' => 'bird',
'melanie' => 'cat'
```

and what i'd like to do is to always take the last 4 items from the array (no matter how big the array is, bearing in mind that it is variable in the amount of items that will be in it), copy them, give each key a different name, but retain the values. So the array would end up like this:

```
'harry' => 'dog',
'bob' => 'badger',
'george' => 'toad',
'fred' => 'frog',
'lucy' => 'bird',
'melanie' => 'cat'
'adam' => 'toad',
'becca' => 'frog',
'tom' => 'bird',
'dave' => 'cat'
```

Thanks very much indeed for any help anyone can give me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`array_slice($array, -4)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) will give you the last 4 values of `$array`. You can then use [`array_combine`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php) to get a new array with these same values and the keys of your choice. Finally, use the [union operator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.array.php) to append the new key/value pairs to the end of the original array.

**[See it in action](http://www.ideone.com/AJQjO)**.

You could also take a number of other approaches, but I believe this one is both short and easily understandable.

Comment: Ah right, it seems i totally misread array_slice. What a tool!